# Javascript regex to replace numbers in sequence

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace numbers in string with the character "X" which works pretty good by replacing every individual number.

This the code:

```
 let htmlStr = initialString.replace(/[0-9]/g, "X");
```

So in a case scenario that `initialString = "p3d8"` the output would be **"pXdX"**

The aim is to replace a sequence of numbers with a single "X" and not every number (in the sequence) individually. For example:

If `initialString = "p348"` , with the above code, the output would be "pXXX". How can I make it "pX" - set an "X" for the whole numbers sequence.

Is that doable through regex?

Any help would be welcome

Comment: Add `+` after `[0-9]`.

Comment: You should read a regexp tutorial, this is one of the most basic patterns.

Comment: If you did substantially edit your question or answers did not work for you, please comment and keep community updated.

Answer (score 8):

Try

```js
let htmlStr = "p348".replace(/[0-9]+/g, "X");
let htmlStr2 = "p348ad3344ddds".replace(/[0-9]+/g, "X");

let htmlStr3 = "p348abc64d".replace(/\d+/g, "X");

console.log("p348           =>",htmlStr);
console.log("p348ad3344ddds =>", htmlStr2);
console.log("p348abc64d     =>", htmlStr3);
```

In regexp the `\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]`, the plus `+` means that we match at least one digit (so we match whole consecutive digits sequence). More info [here](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) or regexp mechanism movie [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwsU2LPs85U).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `+` after `[0-9]` It will match any number(not 0) of number. Check **[Quantifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#quantifiers)**. for more info

```js
let initialString = "p345";
let htmlStr = initialString.replace(/[0-9]+/g, "X");
console.log(htmlStr);
```

Comment: `It will match any number of number.` more precisely it should be atleast one

Comment: @Code Maniac what you mean?

Comment: `+` stands for one or more. `any` can be zero also

Answer (score 0):

Use the `\d` token to match any digits combined with `+` to match one or more. Ending the regex with `g`, the global modifier, will make the regex look for all matches and not stop on the first match.

Here is a good [online tool](https://regex101.com/) to work with regex.

```js
const maskNumbers = str => str.replace(/\d+/g, 'X');

console.log(maskNumbers('abc123def4gh56'));
```